# Populate UITableView swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have this json response from server, how can i populate a UItableView in swift? each Request1 and Request2 in their own cell

```
{
 "Tag": "Get_Client_History",
 "Success": 1,
 "Error": 0,
 "num": 2,
 "Request1": {
   "Request_Id": "10",
   "Date": "2015-10-15 00:00:00",
   "Latitude_In": "24.834987",
   "Longitude_In": "-107.381216",
   "Latitude_Fn": "24.789443",
   "Longitude_Fn": "-107.398201",
   "Name": "Raul Cardenas",
   "Cabbie_Id": "4"
 },
 "Request2": {
   "Request_Id": "20",
   "Date": "2015-10-15 00:00:00",
   "Latitude_In": "24.714987",
   "Longitude_In": "-107.481216",
   "Latitude_Fn": "24.819443",
   "Longitude_Fn": "-107.408201",
   "Name": "Alejandro Rios",
   "Cabbie_Id": "5"
  }
}
```

TableView functions

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return searchResults.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    myCell.textLabel?.text = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    return myCell
}
```

And this is the json the server response

```
let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with tables in iOS is a bit complex comparing to another platforms. The complexity is in usage of `UITableView` class. First, you have to implement both the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols. Then you have to make a view controller on storyboard, place `UITableView` to it and assign your protocols' implementations to the table view as data source and delegate.

Actually, it is not a good idea to start coding while you haven't read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) that describes how to work with `UITableView`. Otherwise you definitely will dive into a lot of architecture mistakes that make you code unmaintanable.

Comment: ok i done that, i implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, i just need the loop for populate the table